# using systemd timers instead of cron

Tags: linux, arch-linux, systemd, systemd-timer

I am on Arch Linux where I am trying to create a systemd timer as a cron alternative for hibernating my laptop on low battery. So I wrote these three files:

**/etc/systemd/system/battery.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Preko skripte preveri stanje baterije in hibernira v kolikor je stanje prenizko

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/home/ziga/Dropbox/workspace/operacijski/archlinux/hibernate/hibernatescript
User=nobody
Group=systemd-journal
```

**/etc/systemd/system/battery.timer**

```
[Unit]
Description=Periodical checking of battery status every two minutes

[Timer]
OnUnitActiveSec=2min 

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

**/home/ziga/Dropbox/workspace/operacijski/archlinux/hibernate/hibernatescript**

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/acpi -b | /usr/bin/awk -F'[,:%]' '{print $2, $3}' | (
        read -r status capacity
        if [ "$status" = Discharging ] && [ "$capacity" -lt 50 ]; then
                /usr/bin/systemctl hibernate
        fi                                                                                                                
)
```

And then to enable timer I executed:

```
sudo systemctl enable battery.timer
sudo systemctl start battery.timer
```

And somehow it isn't working. Script works on its own. This means that if I execute command below, my computer hibernates just fine.

```
/home/ziga/Dropbox/workspace/operacijski/archlinux/hibernate/hibernatescript
```

---

**ADD1:**

After enabling and starting timer I ran some checks and this is what I get:

```
[ziga@ziga-laptop ~]$ systemctl list-timers
NEXT                          LEFT       LAST                          PASSED    UNIT                         ACTIVATES
n/a                           n/a        n/a                           n/a       battery.timer                battery.serv
Tue 2016-06-28 00:00:00 CEST  42min left Mon 2016-06-27 00:01:54 CEST  23h ago   logrotate.timer              logrotate.se
Tue 2016-06-28 00:00:00 CEST  42min left Mon 2016-06-27 00:01:54 CEST  23h ago   shadow.timer                 shadow.servi
Tue 2016-06-28 00:00:00 CEST  42min left Mon 2016-06-27 00:01:54 CEST  23h ago   updatedb.timer               updatedb.ser
Tue 2016-06-28 22:53:58 CEST  23h left   Mon 2016-06-27 22:53:58 CEST  23min ago systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer systemd-tmpf
```

and

```
[ziga@ziga-laptop ~]$ systemctl | grep battery
battery.timer  loaded active elapsed   Periodical checking of battery status every two minutes
```

---

**ADD2:**

After applying solution from **Alexander T** my timer starts (check the code below) but script doesn't hibernate my laptop while it hibernates it if I execute it directly.

```
[ziga@ziga-laptop ~]$ systemctl list-timers
NEXT                          LEFT          LAST                          PASSED       UNIT                         ACTIVATES
Tue 2016-06-28 19:17:30 CEST  1min 43s left Tue 2016-06-28 19:15:30 CEST  16s ago      battery.timer                battery.service
```

Comment: Is it possibly a permissions issue? When you say *you* ran it, was it as the `nobody` user, or as ziga (I see `/home/ziga`)? [User nobody may not have sufficient permissions](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186581/147451). When you say it *isn't working*, how far does it get?

Comment: I have tried to change the user to `ziga` but it doesn't work.

Comment: I tried changing `WantedBy=timers.target`to `WantedBy=battery.service` in **/etc/systemd/system/battery.timer** but this doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An answer to this question is to swap `User=nobody` not with `User=ziga`  but with `User=root` in **/etc/systemd/system/battery.service**. Somehow even if user `ziga` has all the privileges of using `sudo` command it can't execute `systemctl hibernate` inside of the bash script. I really don't know why this happens. So the working files are as follows:

**/etc/systemd/system/battery.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Preko skripte preveri stanje baterije in hibernira v kolikor je stanje prenizko

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/home/ziga/Dropbox/workspace/operacijski/archlinux/hibernate/hibernatescript
User=root
Group=systemd-journal
```

**/etc/systemd/system/battery.timer**

```
[Unit]
Description=Periodical checking of battery status every two minutes

[Timer]
OnBootSec=2min
OnUnitActiveSec=2min 

[Install]
WantedBy=battery.service
```

**/home/ziga/Dropbox/workspace/operacijski/archlinux/hibernate/hibernatescript**

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/acpi -b | /usr/bin/awk -F'[,:%]' '{print $2, $3}' | (
        read -r status capacity
        if [ "$status" = Discharging ] && [ "$capacity" -lt 7 ]; then
                /usr/bin/systemctl hibernate
        fi
)
```

I tried it and it allso works with `User=ziga` or `User=nobody` but we need to change `/usr/bin/systemctl hibernate` into `sudo /usr/bin/systemctl hibernate` in the last script. So it looks like `User` variable somehow doesn't even matter... Oh and you can as well remove absolute names from the last script and change first line from `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash`. I also changed `WantedBy=timers.target` to `WantedBy=battery.service` in **/etc/systemd/system/battery.timer**.

There you go. The best cron alternative to hibernate laptops on low battery. =)

Comment: No part of the system is going to automatically use `sudo`. If you run the systemd service as non-root user, it will execute commands as that user without executing `sudo` unless you explicitly add `sudo`. As a result, the `hibernatescript` is executed as the user defined by `User=ziga` in `.service` file and if that command cannot execute without using `sudo`, it will obviously fail every time. The correct fix is to use `User=root`, not sprinkle `sudo` commands around.

Answer (score 2):

May be you shoul try to add first start after boot, like this:

`[Timer]
OnBootSec=15min
OnUnitActiveSec=2m`

Comment: Did you read this here? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers#Monotonic_timer

Comment: @71GA, Yes, read it there. I think topic starter problem caused by absence of first start.

Comment: This changes some things. Please check my **ADD2** to the question.

Comment: Have you tried to call /usr/bin/systemctl hibernate not from the script? It working? Because when i try to do it n my centos not from root account I get error `Authentication is required for hibernating the system.` and request root password. May be you have same issue and you should start it under `sudo`?

Comment: My user `ziga` is in group `users` and I have this rule `%users ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` in the **/etc/sudoers** file and this rule enables all users  from group `users` to execute `sudo` command without inputting any password. So user `ziga` should be fine right? What kind of user does a systemd service use? I tried setting `User=nobody` and `User=ziga` in **/etc/systemd/system/battery.service** but nothing works.