# Hpux: /etc/group nogroup has -2,what does it mean?

Tags: group, hp-ux

On Hpux

```
grep "nogroup" /etc/group
```

return

```
nogroup:*:-2:
```

Nogroup is name,* mean "shadow" enabled,but what does it mean -2?

Comment: A regrettable choice by Sun when they first designed NFS, eventually corrected to be 65534.  How big are your UIDs? `man limits` will tell you. If they're up to 65536 or so, that means 16 bits, and -2 is 65534.

Comment: Thanks,if add as answer I can close and vote.

Comment: I will wait a bit to see if someone more familiar with hp-ux than I am can confirm this.

Comment: Ok,meanwhile I will search on google,may help.

Comment: There is related information at https://superuser.com/questions/706338/ , https://askubuntu.com/a/674397/43344 , and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186568/ .